# SQL group students by age from date of birth

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a table "student" that features student's "name" and "DOB".

I would like to group students into the following groups:

a. 10-12
b. 13-14
c. 15-16
d. >= 17

so it would appear

a. paul, peter mary
b. john, william
etc.

How would I go about this?

So far I have:

```
 select  case
            when  age between 10 and 12 then a
            when  age between 13 and 14 then b
            when  age between 15 and 16 then c
            when  age >= 17 then d

    from    (
            SELECT  ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Date),
                        Cast(birthday as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
            FROM    db.student
```

but can't seem to get my head around it.

I am using Management Studio.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working?  Are you getting an error?  Also, what DBMS?

Comment: I am using Management Studio.

Comment: So the DBMS would be SQL Server then?  Can you tag accordingly?

Comment: Like roryap said, it would be nice to know what's actually going wrong. Do you have an error message, or faulty result set?

Comment: He says what he wants in his request, he wants a dataset that has a age-cagetgory (a, b, c, etc) and then a variable amount of columns containing names of the students in that age-category. A more important question would be, what is your end-goal for this dataset? There might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query would probably get you the desired results. First, the age is determined. (I added the date format - day - in the `DATEDIFF` function). Then, the age category is determined.

```
WITH ages AS
(
SELECT
    name,
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Date), Cast(birthday as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
FROM db.student
)
SELECT
    name,
    case
                    when  age between 10 and 12 then a
                    when  age between 13 and 14 then b
                    when  age between 15 and 16 then c
                    when  age >= 17 then d
    end as age_category
FROM ages
ORDER BY name;
```